# My Win2D CanvasControl doesn't automatically resize itself based on its content's dimensions. (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, win2d

So I am creating a text editor via Win2D to get past the UWP playtform's `RichEditBox` limitations. Basically I have a `CanvasControl` that I use to draw text to via the `Draw` event's `args.DrawingSession.DrawTextLayout()` method.

The issue is that `CanvasControl` does not resize itself to accommodate content that is being drawn within it. Is there a feature that I am failing to enable, or should this be done manually during each call to the `Draw` event handler? What is the most efficient approach to handling this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CanvasTextLayout.LayoutBounds.Height` is a description of the rendering height inside the `CanvasControl`, but this is not the height of the `CanvasControl` control itself (in fact, `CanvasControl.Height` always shows `NaN` in Debug).

Only when the `Height` property of the `CanvasControl` is greater than the height of the `ScrollViewer`, the scroll bar will be displayed.

So after you render the text, you can manually set the `Height` of the `CanvasControl`.

```cs
// render code
// ...
double height = textLayout.LayoutBounds.Height;
canvasControl.Height = height;
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using that approach. I use "canvasTextLayout.LayoutBounds.Height" as the height for my CanvasControl. I set it during the Draw event call, after setting and styling the text. I figured out that it could work that way, but was still wondering if it was the right approach. Doesn't make sense to me that the CanvasControl itself doesn't have the ability to resize itself based on the width/height of its content. I figured that once I make a call to "args.DrawingSession.DrawTextLayout()", the CanvasControl should resize based on the contents. So I guess I AM doing it right

Comment: Re: "Doesn't make sense to me that the CanvasControl itself doesn't have the ability to resize itself based on the width/height of its content." - it's exactly the opposite; the code doing the drawing is expected to do the drawing based on the size of the Canvas, generally speaking. If you want a container that sizes to your content, Canvas is not the right composition model.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is there a different approach that you would take for what I am doing? I came to the conclusion (somehow) that Win2D's text drawing APIs are good for designing a editor. And IF that is true, then the editor itself needs to resize itself to fit it's very own text content.

Comment: `CanvasControl` as a rendering control, is not designed to be sized based on the content like `Panel`. Inside the `Panel` are controls. When the application is rendered, the controls height are computable, which will affect the layout of other controls. The internal rendering of `CanvasControl` is not necessarily the `Control`. Although the rendering height can be calculated internally, it does not necessarily affect the size of the control itself (such as text overlap).